# Disabling horizontal scrollbar visibility of Webview

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How i can disable horizontal scrollbar visibility  of  WebView control. 
Please find the screenshot of my issue here.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymdhwtvew32rjjs/Facebook%20Image.PNG

Comment: It seems your link is not working 404 error

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot it seems your trying to set up an authentication using a facebook account from your Windows 8 app.

If I am right, you should use instead of a WebView the [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker) which is meant for.

You can find a WebAuthenticationBroker sample on MSDN over [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122).

Also you should take a look to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericsk/archive/2012/07/06/metro-style-app-facebook-authentication-using-webauthenticationbroker.aspx) (use google translate) which talk about it.

Regards.

Comment: sorry !! as per the UI guidelines from the client, i can't use WebAuthenticationBroker. And more over i am facing similar issues in some other views too. I just added the screenshot as a reference not as a part of my implementation. And also the mentioned issue is present in you sample app too. :(